# Unable to import bigquery ScalarQueryParameter

Tags: python, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to import the Query Parameter modules from the bigquery library 0.25.0 onto my google cloud datalab. I am trying to pass this parameters to my query inside a job.

Something in the lines of the below link

http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#querying-data-synchronous

But it keeps throwing module not found.

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import ScalarQueryParameter

ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-f67f6b72bfb9> in <module>()
      1 from google.cloud import bigquery
----> 2 from google.cloud.bigquery import ScalarQueryParameter

ImportError: cannot import name ScalarQueryParameter
```

Am I using the wrong library. Library information below.

Installing collected packages: google-cloud-core, google.cloud.bigquery
  Found existing installation: google-cloud-core 0.22.1
    Uninstalling google-cloud-core-0.22.1:
      Successfully uninstalled google-cloud-core-0.22.1
Successfully installed google-cloud-core-0.25.0 google.cloud.bigquery